# Android 5.1.1 shortcuts

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

I have a new tablet with Android 5.1.1. I am trying to create a shortcut on the home screen by copying a Web page from the Internet Bookmarks.  This was a simple procedure in 4.1, but there is no "Create Shortcut" option in 5.1.1. How do you do this?

Comment: I guess that it depends from your system browser.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Isn't there a bookmark widget anymore in the app drawer with LP?